# Infinite horizontal slider has different animations for prev and next

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider that can have an undefined amount of items and can be scrolled through with two buttons.

This prev and next function both have the same basic idea, to take the needed item and place at either at the end or the start of the div and then animate it using margin-left. Please see below for the code.

**The issue:** The animation is the same on both as long as the buttons are pressed slowly.
However, for some reason this animation is different for both functions if the buttons are pressed rapidly.

For the next function, it is a stepped animation.
For the prev animation, it is a smooth animation but it does overlap with the neighbor item during the transition.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var currentPosition = 0;
var elementCount = slider.childElementCount;

(function() {
    let brand = slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[elementCount - 1];
    slider.insertBefore(brand, slider.firstChild);
    brand.style.marginLeft = '-10%';
})();

window.myFunctionNext = function() {
    let brand = slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0];
    brand.style.marginLeft = '0px';
    slider.appendChild(brand);
    slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0].style.marginLeft = '-10%';
    start=false;
}

window.myFunctionPrev = function() {
    let brand = slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[elementCount - 1];
    brand.style.marginLeft = '-10%';
    slider.insertBefore(brand, slider.firstChild);
    slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[1].style.marginLeft = '0%'; 
}
```

```css
.brands-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.brands-slide {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brands-brand {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: medium;
  font-size: initial;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="brands-wrapper ">
  <div id="wrapper" class="brands-slide animate">
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/91x90" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/91x100" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/491x200" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/191x300" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/41x70" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/91x70" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/91x70" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/77x77" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/88x88" alt="brandname" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunctionPrev()">
    Prev
</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionNext()">
Next
</button>
```

Here is a fiddle with some other ways I have tried, but none have worked so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/rbdLgso7/19/

The ideal solution would be an animation as smooth as prev for both, but without the overlap. Although it would already be good if both would behave the same with either animation.

Comment: Kudos to you for writing animations in vanilla javascript.  This is the sort of stuff I turn to jQuery for, as it simplifies / normalizes a lot of the details...

Comment: @cale_b, using only vanilla for the last week has really opened my eyes as to how much time jquery saves you. Sadly this project needs to be done without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Next / Prev buttons are pressed very quickly, javascrpit is altering the DOM before the CSS transition has a chance to complete. This results in asynchronous transitions when scrolling right. When scrolling left, the leftmost element ( which is still in the process of a margin transition ) is removed from the DOM before the transition is completed, so the new leftmost element snaps into position. No CSS properties were changed in the new leftmost element, so no transition applies.

You should be able to accomplish your goal by adding a control mechanism to your code that ensures  the DOM is not modified until the current transition finishes.

The following javascript, if added to your existing code, should provide a mechanism for continuous synchronous scrolling until the desired scroll target has been achieved.

```
var animation = 0;                              // Which way and how many tiles to rotate
var animate_active = false;                     // Run status

window.myFunctionStart = function() {
    if ( !animate_active ) {                    // Do not start if already running
        setTimeout(myFunctionAnimate, 1);       // Start callback
        animate_active = true;                  // Sets running flag
    }
}

window.myFunctionAnimate = function() {
    if ( animation < 0 ) {                      // If direction = Prev
        myFunctionPrev();                       // Execute transition
        animation += 1;                         // Itterate towards 0
        setTimeout(myFunctionAnimate, 600);     // Continue callback at 0.6s intervals ( should match css transition )
    }
    else if ( animation > 0 ) {                 // If direction = Next
        myFunctionNext();                       // Execute transition
        animation -= 1;                         // Itterate towards 0
        setTimeout(myFunctionAnimate, 600);     // Continue callback at 0.6s intervals ( should match css transition )
    }
    else animate_active = false;                // If no more animations required, stop callback
}
```

To use this code, the next and previous buttons should look like this.

```
<button onclick="animation -= 1; myFunctionStart();">Prev</button>
<button onclick="animation += 1; myFunctionStart();">Next</button>
```

You may also want to change your CSS transition from `ease` to `linear`, otherwise the transition will not look steady.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and the advise, it was very helpful!